# I'm trying to render two columns of information in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have an app that is trying render 2 (or maybe more if needed) columns using a loop.  It does one column and looks pretty good, but I want the option of 2 or even more.  I know about "in_groups.of()", but I can't quite figure it out to work with my

```
<% @vendors.each do |vendor| %>
    <%= link_to vendor do %>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6">
             <div class="card-container">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                 <div class="card">
                   <%= image_tag attachment_url(vendor,     :background_image), class: 'card-img-top' %>
                   <div class="card-block">
                     <h4 class="card-title"><%= vendor.Company %>.        </h4>
                     <p class="card-text"><%= vendor.Description.html_safe.first(25) %></p>
                     <div class="card-standing"><strong><%= vendor.FinancialStanding %></strong></div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you needed this, because everything can be managed with css and html. But you can make changes like this:

```
<% @vendors.to_a.in_groups_of(2).each do |vendor| %> # @vendors.to_a cover AR to array
  <% vendor.each do |v| %> # becuase vendor is array here.
    ..........your code..............
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yeah, I did that before and it (as well as now) threw an undefined method error. Is it best to use css and html to manage looping through to display these in two columns?

Comment: @GabePayne Can you copy and paste the exact error message? Your question post says `in_groups.of` but note that Dipak's answer has `in_groups_of`.

Comment: Oh, right, sorry. I'm an idiot. That's what I meant.   It's saying "undefined method 'vendor_vendor_path'.